# SQL Server - PIVOT/UNPIVOT data by Count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

```html
+----------+----------+----------+
| WORKFLOW | ACCEPTED | REJECTED |
+----------+----------+----------+
| A        |        1 |        1 |
| B        |        1 |        1 |
| C        |        1 |        0 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

I have tried to convert the following data

```
+------------------------------+
| |  ID | WORKFLOW | STATUS  | |
| +--------------------------+ |
| | 1  | A        | Approved | |
| | 2  | A        | Rejected | |
| | 3  | B        | Approved | |
| | 4  | B        | Rejected | |
| | 5  | C        | Approved | |
| +--------------------------+ |
```

INTO this

```
+------------------------------------+
| | WORKFLOW | ACCEPTED | REJECTED | |
| +----------+----------+----------+ |
| | A        |        1 |        1 | |
| | B        |        1 |        1 | |
| | C        |        1 |        0 | |
| +----------+----------+----------+ |
```

But I can't figure how to do it using pivot/unpivot.

Comment: the answer given was only limited to single row. How do I able to have count on Accepted and Rejected for each workflow?

Comment: Already figured it out.  The sql should look like this.


SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT WORKFLOW_NAME, STATUS
FROM [workflow_table]

)d
PIVOT
(COUNT(STATUS) FOR STATUS IN ([Approved],[Rejected])
)pvt